# Migrating TFS 2010 XAML build templates to TFS 2015

Tags: xaml, tfs, tfs-2015

I am upgrading few of my client's TFS 2010 XAML build templates to TFS 2015. Most of the build templates are working fine when compiled with TFS 2015 assemblies. However, one particular build template fails on the build server during build with below error.

`Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.AgileTestPlatformSpec' to type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TestAssemblySpec'`

I have tried many different things including checking for version references in the XAML and also [cleaning](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpricket/2012/07/17/tfs-2012-cleaning-up-workflow-xaml-files-aka-removing-versioned-namespaces/) up the XAML.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are in need to migrate now, it may be a better idea to migrate to the new 2015 build engine. The old XAML engine is considered deprecated and will likely be removed in a future version of TFS. It will be removed from Visual Studio Team Services in September 2016.

Comment: Can you share (part of) the XAML? It's very hard to tell which activity is expecting the TestAssemblySpec and what you're passing to it at the moment. I suspect that a return type of one activity has changed, making it incompatible with the way it's being used in your template.

Comment: @jessehouwing yes, we are migrating few of the builds to new build engine. But my client has around lots of build templates with many custom tasks etc. Moving them will take time. For now, we are moving moderately complex ones to new build system and plan to use xaml builds as is for rest. We plan to move these xaml builds over next few weeks time.

Comment: @jessehouwing I will see if I can share the xaml.

Comment: have you considered keeping the TFS 2010 build controllers around so you can keep the original XAML files around?